# $\int_{|z|=1} \sqrt{9-z^2} \, dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to use local Cauchy theorem to find $\int_{|z|=1} \sqrt{9-z^2} \, dz$.

$\sqrt{9-z^2}$ is not analytic when $9-z^2 \in (-\infty,0]$, which means it's not analytic if $z\geq-\sqrt{3}$, is this correct? So I can't see how to enclose the path on a disk where the function is analytic to use Cauchy!

What am I doing wrong? This got me so confused.

Comment: Isn't the disc $|z|\leq 1$ within the domain of analyticicity, though? Where is the problem?

Comment: @Arthur $z\geq-\sqrt{3}$ is the interval $[-\sqrt{3},\infty)$ in the real axis, so it cuts the circle through its half, doesn't it?

Comment: First off, I think it's $3$ and not $\sqrt3$.  Second, $9-z^2\leq0$ gives $9\leq z^2$ so $z\in (-\infty,-3]\cup[3,\infty)$. So it's unproblematic.

Answer (score 1):

**Trigger warning:** I will use a phrase that is a misnomer under currently prevailing conventions.

The function $z\mapsto\sqrt{9-z^2}$ for $z\in\mathbb C$ is a "double-valued function". It might be better to write it as $z\mapsto\pm\sqrt{9-z^2}$ to emphasize that. There are two points at each of which this "function" has just one value, and those are $z=\pm3.$ Each of those is a branch point: Suppose you start at $z=3+1$ and go in a counterclockwise circle through $3+i,$ then $3+(-1),$ then $3+(-i),$ then back to $3+1,$ while the value of $\pm\sqrt{9-z^2}$ changes in a continuous way, then that value goes from $\sqrt{9-(3+1)^2} = +\sqrt 5,$ the positive square root of $5,$ to $-\sqrt 5,$ the negative square root of $5.$ If you then continue counterclockwise around the circle, then when you return the second time to $3+1,$ the value of the function returns to $+\sqrt5.$

If you go around the circle $|z|=1,$ you do not wind around either $3$ or $-3,$ so you remain on the same branch of the double-valued function $z\mapsto\pm\sqrt{9-x^2},$ and that could be either of the two branches. That function is holomorphic on an open set containing the closed disk whose boundary is that circle. Therefore the integral is $0.$